# Read TimesStamp Data from Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to read firestore data, timestamp data type

variable even though it has been declared as a timestamp,

```
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ServerTimestamp
import java.util.*

data class newsModel(
    var newsTitle: String? = null,
    var newsImage: String? = null,
    var newsSheet: String? = null,
    @ServerTimestamp
    val newsDate: Timestamp? = null
)
```

but appear error like this

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to Timestamp (found in field 'newsDate')

can anybody help me to solve this

[my Code][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvCbq.png

[Error Description][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/843lb.png

[Data in Firestore][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmrys.png

Comment: Are you sure that all your documents hold in the `newsDate` property a Timestamp? I'm afraid that at least one, holds a String. What is the exact code that you are using for reading the data from Firestore?

Comment: timestamp is a long type data type.

Comment: i've used long,,, but it's still error,,,,

Comment: yeah ,, u're right.. when i recheck my data in firestore there is a string data iver there...  